# Why is my nudging inconsistent in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

For context, I am coming from a CorelDraw background and nudging is a very straightforward process of using the arrow buttons and occasionally the Ctrl button to get more precise nudges. However, on Illustrator, when I try to nudge, for example if I want to nudge an object slightly to the left, the nudge works in an inconsistent pattern of something like 5px left, then 10px, then 5px, then 10px and so on...

I tried changing the settings in Illustrator > Preferences > General (on Mac) and changing the Keyboard Increment to as small a value as 0.01px but there was no improvement.

Perhaps someone has experienced something similar or perhaps Illustrator was designed that way and there's an advantage to such behaviour? I am so confused.

I am aware this might be hard to visualise since it is quite strange, so I'm attaching a YT video below

[Video describing my issue so it can be understood better](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzUmNP8OHQU)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: I am unable produce the same results unless I hold Shift + left/right click.  If this happens in a new document as well, then maybe you want to reset Illustrator preferences.

Comment: @Mensch Thank you! Not the typical welcome haha

Comment: @AndrewH  I get that issue without holding Shift. I did reset my preferences however and unfortunately the problem still persists

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDES. Unfortunately I can't reproduce this problem. What version of Illustrator?  Could it be a bug? Maybe check with Adobe.

Comment: wild shot in the dark... Align to Pixel grid? Snap?

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr I am using version 26.0.1 and it could definitely be a bug. I noticed there was an update available and downloaded it but the issue remains. I'll get in contact with Adobe and hopefully find a fix.

Comment: @Scott YES! I noticed the same didn't happen in other files so I checked View and saw that Snap to Grid and Snap to Pixel were both ticked while they weren't in other files. I must have mistakenly ticked those two options. This solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Scott 's helpful comment, I realised that Snap to Grid and Snap to Pixel were both ticked. Unticking those two and leaving Snap to Point and Snap to Glyph selected solved the issue for me.

Comment: Glad that solved it `:)` Little things like this can be horribly frustrating`:)`

Comment: @Scott definitely, I was already getting stressed haha

Comment: Align to pixel should never be used for anything. Why? Well because to do pixel perfect graphics youd need to snap to a 1/2 pixel grid. And presumably your other grid is more usefully sized anyway. In all cases you will be burnt by the particular problems with pixel grid implementation.